# Find out when a fragment is permanently destroyed

Tags: android

Is there a way to find out if a fragment is being permanently destroyed, i.e. that it won't be recreated in the future?

I need this to know when should I destroy a network task associated with the fragment.

Comment: you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Something that should work is to call `getActivity().isChangingConfigurations()` in the fragment's `onDestroy()`.

Comment: the Activity class has `isFinishing()` method, it looks like this one would suit better

Comment: I found that changing tabs (viewpager...) caused my fragments to be destroyed. In that case getActivity().isChangingConfigurations() is false which means its a wrong criteria for activity destruction...

Comment: @chef I disagree actually. When you change tabs, you aren't necessarily going to come back to that tab any time soon, so it's similar to putting the fragment onto the backstack. The activity is destroyed, probably permanently, but you cannot guarantee this. It's sensible to clean up large memory areas from this. However if `isChangingConfigurations` returns true, the fragment is going to immediately be re-created, so you might want to keep stuff in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is associated with a fragment, it should be destroyed in the fragment's `onDestroy` method. The system assumes that all of the fragment's resources have been cleaned up once that method returns, so you should just go ahead and do the required clean-up.

If the fragment is re-created in the future, it will be a whole new fragment so will presumably require a whole new network task anyway.

EDIT:
If you want work to continue in the background when an activity is destroyed and re-created due to a configuration change (such as a screen rotation), you can set up your fragment to not be destroyed. You need to do two relatively simple things:

1. Define your fragment to have no UI (so that it has nothing that needs to be cleaned up when the activity is destroyed).
2. Call [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) for the fragment to prevent the fragment from being destroyed along with the activity. When the activity is re-created after a configuration change, the retained fragment will be reattached. Meanwhile it can continue the background processing.

Comment: Imagine a scenario where the user submits a comment, the UI shows a "sending comment..." message and finally a "comment sent" message. If the user rotates the screen, the fragment gets recreated and this scenario won't work as it should. (Before it's suggested, I decided not to use loaders.)

Comment: In this scenario, a simple solution would be to prevent screen rotation when you are performing sensitive operations such that your fragments do not get recreated and interrupt whatever end goal you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It would be ok for a low-quality app but not the best decision if one cares about UX.

Comment: @fhucho - For that case, you should use a retained fragment to prevent it being destroyed and re-created when an activity is destroyed due to a configuration change (using [`Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)). It should be a headless fragment (no UI) so that it's not tied to the activity's elements.

Comment: @TedHopp fragments can't have child retained fragments. And unless it's a child fragment, the retained fragment won't get destroyed (as it should) when I remove the UI fragment without destroying the activity.

Comment: @fhucho - You hadn't mentioned it being a child fragment before. It's not at all clear to me what all the constraints are, but it sounds like you need to either reorganize your design or add some logic (such as checking whether the activity is finishing inside the fragment's `onStop()` method).

Comment: @TedHopp my fragment has a UI and if I want to use a retained fragment just to hold the background task, it would have to be a child fragment - if it was a non-child fragment, its lifecycle could be different than my UI fragment's lifecycle. Anyway, it's a bit complicated, it would take more time to explain all the details but thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: @fhucho - The whole point is that you _want_ the background task to have a different life cycle than the UI fragment, isn't it? Make the background task a retained fragment of the activity. You can retrieve it from the activity in the UI fragment's `onAttach` method.

Answer (score 0):

This will all depend on how you have created and set up you fragment(s). An easy way to check to see if your fragment(s) is being permanently destroyed is to add a toast or some other sort of notification/flag that you can check in the `onDestroy()` method of the fragment. If you see the toast of if the flag is set then you know that the fragment was destroyed.

Comment: I don't want to check if the fragment is destroyed - but whether it won't be recreated. When the user rotates the screen, the fragment gets destroyed and then created again using the saved state from the old fragment instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, override `onDestroy` and cancel your AsyncTasks or other operations then

```
AsyncTask task;

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (task != null && !task.isCancelled()){
        task.cancel(true);
        task = null;
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I want to cancel the task only when I'm sure that the fragment won't get recreated.